# Radio button not rendering in Safari only

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, safari

I want to create a radio button in a .cshtml file. This simple code is not rendering a radio button in Safari:

```
  <input type="radio" value="1"  name="testme"/>
```

It works perfectly in IE8, but in Safari 5.1.7, radio buttons are not rendered. This happens only for .cshtml files.

Comment: Hi Thanks for this but the ids are same since it is radio button group and in ie8 it works fine for that matter the input type="radio" does not get displayed at all for anything in safari

Comment: This question is lacking a [mcve], and so can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the `overflow:hidden` style for the `<td>` which was causing the radio button not to be rendered in Safari - `overflow:hidden` is behaving differently in Safari.

Answer (score 1):

You should have unique ids. Right now all your input fields have the same id which is invalid HTML. I don't if the rendering issue is related to this but it's a problem that needs fixing. Also AFAIK `param` is an invalid attribute for the `<input>` element.